# Why do I need topology?

Tags: topology

Should I first make a high poly mesh then make low poly mesh based on the high poly mesh so I can animate better or what should I do? Why should I even make new topology, what's the benefit of making it?

Answer (score 1):

A topology is an elementary thing of everything, you can animate high poly sculpt, it would be a pain and your computer would just explode. Good topology makes model deform in a good way with low effort. 
It doesn't matter if you start with low poly from scratch or model a high poly and then do a retopology. As long as you want to manipulate the model and animate it you need the low poly. If the model is just for printing or visual it doesn't matter that much, but even tho good topology makes things easier.